# Android - How to make the recyclerview ListAdpater stop blinking?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-flow, android-listadapter

I have a recycler view whose adapter uses ListAdapter (version 1.1.0) :

```
class InnerEpisodeFragmentAdapter(
    private val actCtx: Context,
) : ListAdapter<Episode, InnerEpisodeFragmentAdapter.MViewHolder>(COMPARATOR) {
...
```

The recycler view is fed by a kotlin flow coming from Room database Episode table :

```
vm.episodesFlow().asLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { episodes ->
  episodes.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
}

@Query("SELECT * FROM Episode ORDER BY pubDate DESC")
fun episodesFlow(): Flow<List<Episode>>
```

As excepted, each time a tuple changes in Episode table, a new list of episodes is emitted and the recycler view is update.

It works fine, but with an horrible BLINK at each update. It gives a bad user experience.

How can I avoid this blinking when the flow emit new values ?

In the previous version of my app, I used functions like notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged() which never blink.I know I could still try to use these functions but I would be very disappointed if I could not avoid the blinks when using the kotlin flow as shown above. Thanks.

Comment: Flow itself shouldn't be the problem here, perhaps there's an issue with your item comparator that fails to recognize unchanged items.

Comment: Can you provide a screen recording.

Comment: Post your `COMPARATOR` code.

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: did you find the answer for this problem? or changing comparator solved your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you comparators

areItemsThesame() is wrongly implemented. What you are comparing is reference where is old object and newObject might not same objects. Instead you some use some kind of uuid to compare the two like primary key. If objects are different it will return false and hence areContentsTheSame will never be called otherwise if objects are same their is no point of comparing contents as both oldObject and newObject are pointing to same reference.

Sorry for errors as I am writing from Mobile

Comment: My question is about the suppression of the blink when the list is updated, not whether or not the list should be updated. My compator works as expected. I just can't stop seeing the recycler view blinking.

Comment: I guess because of comparing every item in list as reference is the cause of blink. In areItemsTheSame comparison should be based on uuId not reference(===) or equals (==)

Comment: Understood. I replaced areItemsTheSame() by : return oldItem.id == newItem.id and only the updated list item is blinking. Though I'd rather the textview within the item to be updated without any blink of the list item, this is acceptable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone faces the problem despite implementing the areContentsTheSame and areItemsTheSame, please set animator of Recyclerview to null like this

```
yourRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

======== REQUESTED ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ======

My comparator is fine and does exactly what I want.
For example, I want isPlayed to be updated in real time in each recycler view item. And it is. But with a blink of the whole list. The recycler view disappears for a fraction of a second then reappear with the updated info.

```
companion object {
    private val COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Episode>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Episode, newItem: Episode): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Episode, newItem: Episode): Boolean {
            return (oldItem.id == newItem.id)
                    && (oldItem.isOnDisk == newItem.isOnDisk)
                    && (oldItem.downloadId == newItem.downloadId)
                    && (oldItem.isPlayed == newItem.isPlayed)
                    && (oldItem.isDeleted == newItem.isDeleted)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be a bit old, but try to avoid using object's equals() in areItemsTheSame(old, new) method. Always try to find some kind of ids and compare them. Otherwise comparing complex object may lead to slow diff and ui lag.